# sumDivs could you help me with my code please

Tags: python

Write a function called sumDivs that accepts a single, positive integer and calculates the
sum of all of its proper divisors. Use a for loop to find and sum the proper divisors of the
given integer.

For example,

```
>>> sumDivs(8)
7
```

this is what i have:

```
def sums(n):
    i=0
    for i in range (1, n-1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return n-1 
        i+=1
```

Comment: What's the question?  What results do you get from your code?

Comment: If you do `return n-1` in the middle of your loop, that's going to return from the function. That can't be what you want. Clearly if you want to sum up some numbers, you need to store the total in some kind of variable that you repeatedly add to, so you can return the total at the end.

Comment: Also, `for i in range(1, n-1)` already makes `i` take on all the values from `1` to `n-2`; there's no reason to set `i=0` beforehand, or do `i+=1` in the middle of the loop. (Also, why `n-1` instead of `n` in the first place? There actually _is_ a reason if you know what you're doing… but there's a much better reason to use something different instead, which would be obvious… so I suspect that's not your reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't return the first divisor you find, you should be adding them as you go; i takes on the values from 1 to n-2 in your loop change to `for i in range(1,n)`; and there is no need to define an initial value for i. Try this instead:

```
def sums(n):
    sum=0
    for i in range (1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            sum+=i 
    return sum
```

Comment: thank you, i saw where i went wrong

Comment: @kady484: If the answer was useful for you, could you please accept it to notify that you no longer need help for this question ?